# Apple Push Notification Servive costs

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I don't find any thing about the costs to make Push notifications to my iPhone app.
I want to send Push Notifications to my App, but I don't find anything about the Price.

What does it cost to send Push Notifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your own server, you can do it for free. Depending on the language you use, there are good libraries available. With JVM languages, you can use [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/), for example.

It is also possible to use an external company that specializes in this. I have found [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com) is good for my needs and has a free usage tier (I have no association with them).

Bottom Line: If you use external suppliers prices will vary, and you will either find them on their website, or by asking. Apple does not charge you anything. Doing it yourself is free.

Comment: I have a own Server.

I found some Libaries for php, and when I make it own with the Libaries it is free?

Comment: Then you can do it for free. Apple does not charge